# Finding entries containing a substring in a numpy array?

Tags: numpy, where-clause, python-3.4, string-comparison

I tried to find entries in an Array containing a substring with np.where and an in condition:

```
import numpy as np
foo = "aa"
bar = np.array(["aaa", "aab", "aca"])
np.where(foo in bar)
```

this only returns an empty Array.
Why is that so?
And is there a good alternative solution?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We can use [`np.core.defchararray.find`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.array.html) to find the position of `foo` string in each element of `bar`, which would return `-1` if not found. Thus, it could be used to detect whether `foo` is present in each element or not by checking for `-1` on the output from `find`. Finally, we would use `np.flatnonzero` to get the indices of matches. So, we would have an implementation, like so -

```
np.flatnonzero(np.core.defchararray.find(bar,foo)!=-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [91]: bar
Out[91]: 
array(['aaa', 'aab', 'aca'], 
      dtype='|S3')

In [92]: foo
Out[92]: 'aa'

In [93]: np.flatnonzero(np.core.defchararray.find(bar,foo)!=-1)
Out[93]: array([0, 1])

In [94]: bar[2] = 'jaa'

In [95]: np.flatnonzero(np.core.defchararray.find(bar,foo)!=-1)
Out[95]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: this works perfectly. Thank you very much! But out of curiosity do you know why the in condition in np.where  doesnt work?

Comment: @SiOx AFAIK `foo` being a NumPy array doesn't work with `in`. That `in` is meant for Python lists, etc. if that makes sense?

Comment: `in` does work with an array, that is `ndarray` has a `__contains__` method.  But behavior is similar to that of list.

Comment: `np.char.find` is the shorthand for this function.

Comment: this does only work partly when there is no space in there. if elements ' aaa' and ' aab' is used for the case above, (which has the space at the very front) it would not work

Comment: @IsaacSim Yeah, because that `space` is a character in itself.

Comment: then if that case, how can I find ?

Comment: @IsaacSim Use `python strip function`?

Comment: I already used before you gave me an advice, but thanks a lot ! I am just not happy that I have to do strip. that will also trying to find wrong answer because the substring can be found from the words concatenated  = [

Comment: @IsaacSim Maybe post a question on Stackoverflow, so that we all can have a better look at the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Look at some examples of using `in`:

```
In [19]: bar = np.array(["aaa", "aab", "aca"])

In [20]: 'aa' in bar
Out[20]: False

In [21]: 'aaa' in bar
Out[21]: True

In [22]: 'aab' in bar
Out[22]: True

In [23]: 'aab' in list(bar)
```

It looks like `in` when used with an array works as though the array was a list.  `ndarray` does have a `__contains__` method, so `in` works, but it is probably simple.

But in any case, note that `in alist` does not check for substrings. The `strings` `__contains__` does the substring test, but I don't know any builtin class that propagates the test down to the component strings.

As `Divakar` shows there is a collection of numpy functions that applies string methods to individual elements of an array.

```
In [42]: np.char.find(bar, 'aa')
Out[42]: array([ 0,  0, -1])
```

> Docstring:
>   This module contains a set of functions for vectorized string
>   operations and methods.
>   The preferred alias for `defchararray` is `numpy.char`.

For operations like this I think the `np.char` speeds are about same as with:

```
In [49]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.find('aa'), 1, 1)(bar)
Out[49]: array([0, 0, -1], dtype=object)

In [50]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x: 'aa' in x, 1, 1)(bar)
Out[50]: array([True, True, False], dtype=object)
```

Further tests suggest that the `ndarray` `__contains__` operates on the `flat` version of the array - that is, shape doesn't affect its behavior.

Answer (score 5):

If using `pandas` is acceptable, then utilizing the `str.contains` method can be used.

```
import numpy as np
entries = np.array(["aaa", "aab", "aca"])

import pandas as pd
pd.Series(entries).str.contains('aa') # <----
```

Results in:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

The method also accepts regular expressions for more complex patterns:

```
pd.Series(entries).str.contains(r'a.a')
```

Results in:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are trying to use `np.where` is incorrect.  The first argument of `np.where` should be a boolean array, and you are simply passing it a boolean.

```
foo in bar
>>> False
np.where(False)
>>> (array([], dtype=int32),)
np.where(np.array([True, True, False]))
>>> (array([0, 1], dtype=int32),)
```

The problem is that numpy does not define the `in` operator as an [element-wise boolean operation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html).

One way you could accomplish what you want is with a list comprehension.

```
foo = 'aa'
bar = np.array(['aaa', 'aab', 'aca'])
out = [i for i, v in enumerate(bar) if foo in v]
# out = [0, 1]

bar = ['aca', 'bba', 'baa', 'aaf', 'ccc']
out = [i for i, v in enumerate(bar) if foo in v]
# out = [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
mask = [foo in x for x in bar]  
filter = bar[ np.where( mask * bar != '') ]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!  While this answer may solve the problem it does not try to answer the question of **why** the original code wasn't working.  Could you please edit your question to explain this too?  Thanks!