# numpy.where contains string condition

Tags: python, numpy

To improve the execution time, I replaced a comprehension list with a condition in with np.where(). It works fine where the value matches but i want to have a condition where the value is in the string not equal:

```
import numpy as np
currencies = np.array(["USD","NZL","EUR","KWR"])
currencie = [x for x in list(currencies) if x in "USDKLR EUR"]
#returns ["USD","EUR"]
#What works:
currencie = currencies[np.where(currencies == "EUR")]
#returns ["EUR"]
```

What I want is the in condition but using np.where or numpy function, no list treatement.

```
currencie = currencies[np.where(currencies in "USDKLR EUR")]
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `where` is only as good as its condition argument.  It isn't an iterator.  It just finds the True elements.  While numpy has a set of string functions, they use string methods and aren't any faster than list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question has basically already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974168/finding-entries-containing-a-substring-in-a-numpy-array).

Solution would be:

```
In [6]: currencie = currencies[ 
   ...:     np.where( 
   ...:         np.core.defchararray.find( 
   ...:             "USDKLR EUR", currencies 
   ...:         ) != -1 
   ...:     ) 
   ...: ]                            

In [7]: currencie                                                                                                             
Out[7]: array(['USD', 'EUR'], dtype='<U3')
```

For explanation see the linked question.

Comment: `np.char.find` also works.